# PassengerTempDir issue ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, redmine

I have trouble while trying to set PassengerTempDir:

I have redmine on apache+mod_passenger, CentOs. In redmine I have 500 Internal Error while uploading files. Due to my issue I have found that I should change PassengerTempDir to custom folder.

[wrong permissions set in the webserver_private directory of passenger.](http://www.warden.pl/2010/10/27/rails-application-crashing-when-trying-to-upload-files-with-mod_passenger/)

[6.6 PassengerTempDir](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache%204.0.html#PassengerTempDir)

For tests I have create folder /home/tmp_passenger and set 777 for it.

And the next I proceed `export PASSENGER_TMPDIR=/tmp_passenger`

Result is :

```
 passenger-status
 ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.
```

So, before I have proceed `export PASSENGER_TMPDIR=/tmp_passenger`

```
 passenger-status
 Version : 4.0.53
 Date    : 2014-12-29 12:43:36 +0100
 Instance: 1416
 ----------- General information -----------
 Max pool size : 20
 Processes     : 1
 Requests in top-level queue : 0

 ----------- Application groups -----------
 /home/admin/web/MYDOMAIN/public_html/redmine#default:
 App root: /home/admin/web/MYDOMAIN/public_html/redmine
 Requests in queue: 0
 * PID: 6440    Sessions: 0       Processed: 8       Uptime: 22m 1s
 CPU: 0%      Memory  : 52M     Last used: 10m 29s ago
```

After I have proceed `export PASSENGER_TMPDIR=/tmp_passenger`

```
 passenger-status
 ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.
```

Please, help me resolve issue. What I should do now ?